# Apple MDM push error, but only to some iOS devices

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We have error with MDMpush on some iPhone devices:

> Jul 30 17:52:46 Mirnas-iPhone apsd[49] : : Stream error occurred for : Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "The operation couldn’-t -b-e
>   -c-o-m-p-l-e-t-e-d-. -C-o-n-n-e-c-t-i-o-n -r-e-s-e-t -b-y -p-e-e-r-" -U-s-e-r-I-n-f-o-=-0-x-1-4-3-5-4-0 -{-}

All devices are the same, same iOS version, but on 50% of devices we have this error. On other devices push is working perfectly. Devices with this problem checks in without problem during MDM payload installation, but when we try to push something, error happens.

Comment: What are you using push notifications for?  If it's something like ads, its possible users have an app that is blocking connections intentionally.

Comment: We are using it for MDM push, new payloads, etc. Just basic push test is not working without any commands for iOS device.

Comment: Perhaps the user has chosen to not receive push notifications from your app and you are still using their device token.  You are supposed to 'unregister' their device token if they choose not to receive notifications. Perhaps...

Comment: Is this really a problem? It looks like the device just lost the connection to the push service. It will probably reconnect and then receive the push. Did the device try to connect to the MDM service? Maybe something logged by the MDM process of the device?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem if you're using same certification for different device. You have to do a clean, then build and run the application onto the device. Remove the previous installed application which is using same certification (same application).

Answer (score 1):

We had similar symptom long time ago, it was caused by someone changed the Apple MDM certificate after half of the devices enrolled. some device was enrolled with new cert, and rest are enrolled by old cert.  the apple MDM server does not like this.

You need to enroll all the device with same cert.